# Adding style to columns that are individually written to excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, styles

I am attempting to style and then write individual columns to an existing excel sheet. However I keep receiving an error.

```
def color_green(val):
color = 'green' if val != 'CHECK' else 'black'
return 'color: %s' % color

#apply color
df['Name'] = df['Name'].style.applymap(color_green)

#write col to excel
df['Name'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet1', startrow = 12, startcol = 2, index=False, header=False )
```

The error that I am receiving:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'style'
```

I have several different columns that need to be styled and written in the same way.

Comment: Documentation says:`For Styler.applymap your function should take a scalar and return a single string ... For Styler.apply your function should take a Series or DataFrame..., and return a Series or DataFrame ...` I don't really know anything about `pandas` but that jumped out to me as a possible issue.

Comment: @EmilyAlden Thanks for the reply, I played around with both and still got the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think you can try using double braces `[[]]` to call this under a dataframe or use the `subset` parameter under `applymap()` like below*:

```
df[['Name']].style.applymap(color_green).to_excel(path,index=False)
```

Another way would be:

```
df.style.applymap(color_green, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Name']])
```

this results in the full dataframe styled in a list of specific columns.

***For better understanding, an example in below:***

Demo:

Lets consider the following df:

```
   Name  some_col
0    abc         1
1  CHECK         1
2   defg         2
3  CHECK         3
4    efg         3
5    ijk         3
6    lmn         1
7    opq         7

def color_green(val):
    color = 'green' if val != 'CHECK' else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
df[['Name']].style.applymap(color_green)
```

***this outputs***

[image]

the second method:

```
df.style.applymap(color_green, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Name']])
```

*this outputs:*

[image]

You can then export this in excel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MaxB My Pleasure..!! Cheers. :)

Comment: any idea what might raise the following error: "style is not supported for non-unique indicies."? It seems to still be working on non-unique indices so I am confused why it is giving me this error?

Comment: @MaxB looks like you have duplicate index . You can reset the index fist i.e `df=df.reset_index(drop=True)` before doing the style. :)